# I want a simple example how to send Coordinates that i get as sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is The Source Code Of my javascript moveing object,Could you just simply modify this Code or just Tell me Where should i Start from To use sockets here i know NodeJs on Beginner stage but there is no tutorial For Sockets So it's confusing How can i Just Send my Coordinates To sockets and Write a Response For that Coordinates.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>GameTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#img{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
 </style>
<img id="img" src="hand.png">
<script>
var player=document.getElementById('img');
var x=0;
var y=0;
function movePlayer(event){
 if(event.keyCode==39){
    x+=2;
 player.style.left=x+'px';
 }
if(event.keyCode==37){
    x-=2;
    player.style.left=x+'px';
}
if(event.keyCode==38){
    y-=2;
    player.style.top=y+'px';
}
 if(event.keyCode==40){
    y+=2;
    player.style.top=y+'px';
}
if(event.keyCode==40&&event.keyCode==37){
    y-=2;
    x+=2;
    player.style.top=y+'px';
    player.style.lef=x+'px';
 }
    getCoordinates(player);
 }
 document.addEventListener('keydown',movePlayer);
 function getCoordinates(el){
while(el&&isNaN(el.offsetLeft)&&isNaN(el.offsetTop)){
x+=el.offsetLeft-el.scrollLeft;
y+=el.offsetTop-el.scrolltop;
el=el.offsetParent;
}
console.log( {top:y,left:x});
}
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install socket.io

```
 npm install socket.io
```

create server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('coordinates', function (data) {
     socket.emit('coordinates', data);
  });
});
```

in index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
 document.addEventListener('keydown',socket.emit({x:3,y:10}));
  socket.on('coordinates', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
     //use data.coordinates here

  });
</script>
```

In your addEventListener you can call getCoordinates or update coordinates  in which you can call socket.emit(//cordinatees//);